# Could a merchant city survive not having an military?

Tags: medieval, cities, military

Picture a city set in the renaissance times (circa 1350, for example), a city surrounded by vast rich soil at the lip of a large bay. Given the city's close proximity to larger ally kingdoms (kingdoms with large naval fleet and standing armies), there are little to no outside threats to the city itself. There is an internal City Guard that upholds the law within the city walls. The city exports many important agricultural goods to the rest of the continent via ships. It is a merchant city.

Could a city like this ever survive under the umbrella of the larger kingdoms? At minimum, what sort of military would it need to defend itself?

Comment: You seem to be asking a lot of questions at once. We have a strict one question per post policy. It seems like a lot would depend on the specific political climate of the region, and the actions taken by rulers and their rivals to further their personal motives. That makes this question highly dependent upon the authorial discretion of whoever is writing the history of the region, which in this case would be you. Such highly subjective questions are also not appropriate.

Comment: edited the number of questions, thanks

Comment: We'll also need more information about the "larger kingdoms". Are all adjacent territories superior in size, army, wealth? What are their political connections? If it has a large amount of trader's ships coming in and out, they apparently feel safe enough to have valuable cargo.

Comment: -1 for lack of research. There were [many city-states during the renaissance times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City-state) with varying degrees of military expression. Surely a review of the nature of those cities would answer your question. If not, please explain why.

Comment: Assuming that by "an military" means a standing army, what cities do you know in the mid-14th century which *had* standing armies? (Most people would say that 1350 is a full century before the beginning of the Renaissance; but if you want to call 1350 "Renaissance" then the city must be either Florence or Genoa, or *maybe* other smaller north Italian city. All others were still hard in the Middle Ages. Yes, Venice did show early signs of Renaissance, but by 1350 is was no longer a city-state but rather the [capital of decent-sized empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stato_da_Màr).)

Comment: Luckily for you, this question has been answered by none other than Niccolo' Machiavelli, knock yourself out (chapters 12-14 being the most relevant): https://standardebooks.org/ebooks/niccolo-machiavelli/the-prince/w-k-marriott/text

Answer (score 10):

**City walls.**

[image: tyre]

https://www.the961.com/alexander-the-great-siege-of-phoenician-tyre/

Your merchant city on the water has circumferential walls.  Depicted: Tyre.  Alexander the Great did eventually defeat Tyre and so too your city will fall if there is a serious army or navy that attacks it.  But if Tyre can hold out against Alexander for months, your city walls and the city guard (supplemented by a volunteer militia of city dwellers) can hold out against small time pirate chiefs or renegade armed groups that think it will be an easy target.

My understanding (correct me, AlexP) is that for the last few hundred years of its existence Constantinople was similar - the lone city remnant of an empire, no longer with an army or navy able to project power, but safe behind the giant walls built in its salad days.  Until it was not.

Comment: *"Last few hundred years"* is a stretch. Last 50 years is more like it, and it never was reduced to only the city. Constantinople had been captured by the barbarian Franks in 1204, so that between 1204 and 1261 the Eastern Roman Empire was let's say *suspended*. (Eastern Europe has not yet forgiven the West for this.) In 1261 the Franks were finally expelled and the Romans recovered Thrace, Macedonia, northern Greece, and the Troad in Asia. By 1350 they had lost all Asian possessions. In 1400 they had only a small part of Thrace, the Chersonese and bits of the Peloponnese.

Comment: [Here is a map](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:1389_Mediterranean_Sea.PNG) of the moribund Roman Empire (lavender) and the nascent Ottoman Empire (dark green) towards the end of the 14th century. (The light green is various self-headed Turkic states which  one way or another were going to become part of the Ottoman Empire.) (The Ottomans postponed taking Constantinople to 1453 because they had a [spot of trouble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timur) with a certain [*Tamburlaine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamburlaine).)

Answer (score 6):

## They can hire mercenaries.

Lots of cities relied heavily on hired mercenaries in the event of a war. They are next to an allied kingdom which presumably has a large military. If they need soldiers for some reason they can just use their vast wealth to hire mercenaries.

Raiders, internal dissidents, pirates, wars with enemies of their allies and lots of issues could cause a need for a large formal military. That said, so long as their ally has enough mercenaries if they need one they can just hire mercenaries from them in the rare emergencies when they need them.

## If the continent gets more chaotic they'll need an army.

If enough wars are ongoing mercenaries will be hired by rivals and they'll run out of people. Then you need your own army.

Comment: Would hiring mercenaries be frowned upon? When I think mercenaries I think of scumbags with swords.

Comment: It was very common in the past, numerous countries hired mercenaries. It's very common today. They didn't have a much worse reputation than armies, which pillaged their way through land routinely. Armies that are poorly paid tend to be scumbags with swords. Pay them well enough and they have no need to forage off the land. 

They would presumably have reputable, honorable companies to hire mercenaries from that were trusted to not pillage their people.

Comment: @NepeneNep I'm no expert on mercenaries in general but their history in England is pretty sordid. Foreign mercenaries played a big role in the Anarchy and under some of the Plantagenets and were definitely hated more than ordinary soldiers. The lack of natural affection for their countrymen and their greed made them noticably nastier under tyrannical kings than typical soldiers, even though they were pretty nasty too.

Comment: At particular times certain mercenary groups or armies had a bad reputation, but it was hardly a universal thing. Lots of English armies got a bad reputation, say in Ireland.

Comment: Agreed re: Ireland, but then,  English armies in Ireland were foreign. The 'foreign soldiers will do nastier things to the local people' theme is pretty well documented, e.g. in Plantagenet England, colonial America, Russia (e.g. the Cossacks), WW2. This by itself would explain why mercenaries used to quell internal dissent tended to be ruthless;hiring foreign mercenaries could be a strategy deliberately chosen for ruthlessness. It does seem the Italians had better experiences with mercenaries, not sure why though.

Comment: @Ebi And? So what if they're swords with scum bags? Do you want your merchant city to be conquered or not? Who are you trying to impress here being worried about being frowned upon? The regular soldiers whom you don't have enough of to defend the city? Or the citizens who cannot or are unwilling to fight?

Comment: @ebi look up Federico da Montefeltro, a mercenary leader who was famous for both never losing and impeccable honor, and for founding a public university in his dukedom. a good mercenary knows reputation is important.

Comment: Hiring mercenaries to defend Italian renaissance city-states was so common a practice that Machiavelli wrote a whole chapter of *the Prince* to deplore it and advocate for a local militia instead: "I conclude, therefore, that no principality is secure without having its own forces; [...] [a]nd one’s own forces are those which are composed either of subjects, citizens, or dependents; all others are mercenaries or auxiliaries. " https://standardebooks.org/ebooks/niccolo-machiavelli/the-prince/w-k-marriott/text/chapter-13

Answer (score 4):

### A "protectorate"

If this city is such a cornucopia, the powerful states on its doorstep will come to depend on it. If those states have prudent, far-sighted rulers, they will take steps to guarantee that this city is not seized, sacked, or left to seed. If they think it necessary, they will take it by force to ensure that it continues to be managed effectively and that its wares flow freely into their supply chain.

Less drastically, they will seek become intertwined politically, not just by diplomacy, but by merging with the city's ruling class through marriage. I would also expect a significant amount of espionage.

These states will also probably make it clear to their other neighbors that they'll treat any attack on or interference with this city as an attack on themselves.

It is entirely possible that, depending on how political power works in its neighboring states, this city may find it has practically no power over its own fate. (Yes, a political system can exist where the merchant class is *not* able to transform its wealth directly into political might. Rich people can also have their property seized by the state if the state considers that wealth to be a rival power center.)

Answer (score 3):

**A Militia**

The city does not have a standing army, but instead treats the bearing of arms and fighting as a civic obligation. It was quite common in the Middle Ages for cities to have crossbow or archery shooting clubs, and cities could field surprisingly competent infantry forces drawn from their citizens. For one example see the Battle of the [Golden Spurs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Golden_Spurs) which featured a large militia army drawn from Flemish cities pull a huge upset victory over the French knightly army.

Answer (score 3):

#### [Luxembourg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxembourg)

Luxembourg sits on the border of France, Germany and Belgium.  Historically this made it the first stop for any of these major powers invading their neighbours, and it changed hands repeatedly.  Due to this, each invading army successively strengthened the defences of Luxembourg City, effectively turning the city into a vast, hugely-fortified citadel.

After Napoleon's defeat in 1815, Luxembourg officially became independent but was somewhat passed around for a few decades.  Its status was finally settled in 1866 by the Prussians (Germans) and Belgians agreeing to make it an independent state, on the conditions that all the city defences were dismantled.  Both could see the economic benefits of trade through a free Luxembourg, but neither of them entirely trusted the other.  Demolishing the defences guaranteed that if either of them invaded Luxembourg, they would be unable to hold it against a reasonably well-matched opponent.

This could work well for landlocked countries/cities.  Any attacking force has to come overland, so you know who it could be.  If the neighbouring countries are reasonably evenly matched, they may find the "bird in the hand" of successful trade to be worth more than the "two in the bush" of a risky war.

The issue you have is the "bay" part.  Until the invention of guided missiles, the most potent military power was always projected from ships.  Even today, ship-based artillery is more powerful than anything on land, and that was even more the case historically.  And sea borders give endless options for landing troops to attack from any direction.  As attackers have long realised from [Vikings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikings), to [Francis Drake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Drake), to [the commandos of the Saint-Nazaire raid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Nazaire_submarine_base), you simply can't defend  a coastal border effectively.  You can stop the attackers at sea, or you can retreat to sacrifice land and stop them further on when their supply lines are weaker, but you can't stop them getting ashore when they're there.  This makes your bay a profound weak spot.  And worse, a sheltered bay is automatically a significant military objective for anyone wanting to push inland.

**Tl;dr: Without the bay, it could work.  With the bay, you're dead and you just don't know it yet.**

Comment: Thank you. Very informative. What if instead of a bay, a river ran through the city? A river wide enough for merchant ships to sail on? The river leads to a bay, say, 30 miles away.

Comment: @Ebi That's  more of a working idea, and historically all major cities were on rivers because overland transport was impossible. If the neighbouring kingdoms control the coast, then cities inland have less reason to be worried about invaders.

Answer (score 2):

### Careful balancing of power

Your city survives by making the risks of attacking it greater than the rewards.  It is neutral ground to allow trading, for instance.  It does not play favorites with its goods.  Every kingdom would prefer to have it for itself, but knows that any attempt is liable to bring down the wrath of other kingdoms, because it would mean they lose the advantages.  Consequently the risk is great.

In this situation, raising an army might actually imperil it.  "What does it want an army for?" ask the kingdoms.  Is it thinking of acting against their interests?  Given they can probably attack, and even coordinate an attack, before it can raise a large enough force to hold them off, safety lies in not provoking it.

Comment: Great answer. This is what I want to achieve, to have a city that is untouchable due to consequences.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your city to not be attacked over a long period of time, then having an army is not sufficient anyway; you want there to be no reason to attack it in the first place, and then having an army may not be necessary anyway.

- If your city controls valuable natural resources, then it will eventually be attacked by others who want those resources for themselves. This one is easy: there are no significant natural resources in or around your city. Their wealth comes from their status as a centre for trade.
- A bordering nation may want to annex your city if doing so would reduce the size of their own border with some other hostile nation, making their own national defense easier. This one is also fairly easy: your city sits on the intersection of the borders between three nations much larger than it, so conquering the city would not reduce the length of any border.
- Your city might be attacked if there is a conflict between two other nations, and the city is seen by one side as supporting the other. Solution: your city is strictly neutral on all geopolitical matters, they will happily continue to trade with all sides of any conflict, and they will even arrange for different marketplaces in the city to cater for opposing factions, so that visiting traders from those factions don't have to meet each other. Or, they offer deliveries to buyers whom it would be too dangerous to invite. The only people your city refuses to trade with are those who try to attack the city.
- A city with a substantial population of ethnic minorities might become a target for ethnic cleansing, if your world has any kind of racial animus. A possible solution is to make at least this region ethnically homogeneous.
- Religious zealots might want to conquer your city in order to convert the citizens. The easiest solution is to just make religion not a significant source of conflict in your world; perhaps there is only one religion, or none. However, if you do want your world to have multiple major religions, then your city could be predominantly one religion and there could be a nearby state with sufficient military power, which protects your city against religiously-motivated attacks because they want their own religion to remain dominant in the region.

Answer (score 1):

1. **History** - the city has a history of providing neutral and efficient banking and other financial services to the lords and leading citizens of surrounding neighboring kingdoms. Not just that it houses banks (which it does) but it also operates branches and agents in every major kingdom and owns or controls (via debt) valuable assets such as shipping companies etc
2. Together with the above the city also has, during some great historical crisis of the past been the site of one or more historic meetings between rival powers where important treaties were settled.
3. The city has entered into a series of historical non-aggression packs with all neighboring kingdoms and has a history of remaining strictly neutral during wars between them. (And has strictly enforced that neutrality which greatly enhances its value as a financial center and refuge in times of crisis).
4. **Geography**- the city is easily approachable by sea but more difficult to approach by land. Perhaps a series of mountain passes mean it is shut off on the landward from it's neighbors during the cold season or in bad weather or is otherwise difficult to approach (marshes and rivers instead of mountains). On top of that the city itself asserts control over a relatively small amount of territory beyond its walls i.e the same physical barriers that isolate it restrict the amount territory it governs to a creatively small amount of land. Small enough that it adds little in the way of size or population to it's immediate neighbors.
5. Its *has* been conquered in in the past but for all the reasons stated above plus local opposition the 'conquest' has never stuck with the hostile power eventual agreeing (or being forced to) withdraw  after a short time because the cities inhabitants have used their financial and political connections to make life for the conquering nation more difficult than staying was worth.

In short? Sort of be like Switzerland (and yes, it can also hire out mercenaries if it thinks its might be profitable!)

Comment: Be careful with the banking. European kings have a history of taking out a lot of loans and then taking actions against the banks so that they don't have to repay the loans.

Comment: True, but the banks still survived and prospered and as I said they did operate lots of branches and own other assets.

Answer (score 1):

**There could be huge political ramification for attacking such a city.*

From your description, this town could either be a neutral ground for trading, a manufacture powerhouse with contracts everywhere or a place of great investment. In all of these scenarios attempting a military incursion on that city would make more enemies, steering the political and economic stability of that region. And if the attack is a long time coming, the merchants could simply muster up support from their business partners.

Answer (score 1):

How about the situation is reversed? That is, all around the city is a military strong-hold. Here, camps train super-warriors, craftspeople make the most advanced weapons, alchemists make the most advanced materials.

All those people need raw materials, food and leisure facilities. Your city provides them all. The city provides the place the alchemist sells materials, and the blacksmiths buy them, and so on. Perhaps roads through the military areas provide trade routes for external goods to be bought and sold. Everyone visiting enjoys a drink in the pub, or a meal at a restaurant.

As others have suggested, the city has walls, within which no military exists - and perhaps even has laws that prohibit carrying weapons of various types. In some sense, it's almost "inverse military", neutrality, peace and safety - the lack of military standing or attitude is actually the goal of the place.

An internal police force maintains the rules and order, but there's no army within the city. Any external invader would need to convince the surrounding military camps that an attack was in their interests. The city though, provides good things to these camps, so they're disinclined to allow any attacker to get near.

The obvious question is what does this city offer that's so special? Well, perhaps its rule and order is in fact it's secret sauce. Any disagreements are resolved by some sort of impartial fair method, which for whatever reason the local militaries just can't replicate, perhaps because they're full of machismo, ego or perhaps are bred with aggressive tendencies, and so aren't disposed to negotiate.

Also, erm, sexual gratification facilities are hard to replicate for militaries, and have historically been somewhat essential. Perhaps again careful regulation makes such things safe, fair and available.